# Search pull requests / merges by commit message and cherry-pick all corresponding commits

Tags: git, intellij-idea, atlassian-sourcetree

Consider the following history:

```
      #1    #2    #3   PR no.

-O-----A-----B-----C   commits on master (merges)
  \   / \   / \   /
   1-2   3-4   5-6     commits on branches
```

As can be seen, there were 3 PRs, merged via the commits A, B, C. The commit messages of these merges contain issue keys:

- A: "Merge FIB-13 ..."
- B: "Merge FIB-21 ..."
- C: "Merge FIB-34 ..."

Now I would like to search for certain issues and get a list of the commits that they introduced:

```
Input: List of issue keys
Output: List of commits from PRs

Example
-------

Input: FIB-13, FIB-34
Output: 1, 2, 5, 6
```

Afterwards, I would like to cherry-pick these commits into another branch, commit by commit:

```
-1-2-5-6   another branch
```

Is there a good way to script this and/or can this be achieved via IntelliJ's Git client or Sourcetree?

Comment: _"search for certain issues and get a list of the commits that they introduced"_ are you looking for git-bisect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, I have to find merge commits by a certain string, get the commits they introduced and cherry-pick them.

Comment: How would you know which commits they introduced? Which parent are you going by? Or does one path only contain merge commits?

Comment: @evolutionxbox exactly, `master` mostly consists of merges. I'm always interested in the parent/path from the other branches. In the example above, for merge A follow commit 2, for merge C commit 6.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585874/how-do-you-find-who-merged-a-git-commit-into-a-branch

Comment: It looks like you want to find merge commits via `git log --first-parent --merges master` (or the equivalent with `git rev-list`), then use those and their messages to run a second log or rev-list using the second parent of the specified merges, with a "stop" (start?) point specified by the first parent of the corresponding merge. That's pretty simple as a *shell* script; I avoid GUIs, which generally are quite useless for this sort of thing, so I don't know if IntelliJ's client or Sourcetree are any good for that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thx for the pointer, but I think this is the case where know e.g. commit 5 and want to find merge commit C.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @larsks I'm not expecting anyone to write code for me (or someone else). An answer may contain an incomplete script, steps to follow using a specific Git client, etc. What I have done so far: (meanwhile) I know how to obtain the relevant merges, but I'm a bit stuck when it comes to finding and cherry-picking the commits these merges have introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read in the comments, the first obstacle you encountered is finding all the commits you want to `git cherry-pick`. As proposed by @torek, it can be easily done with `git log` or `git rev-list`. Basically something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
first_log="git rev-list --reverse --merges"
for feature in $@ 
do
    first_log+=" --grep=\"^Merge ${feature}\"" 
done

for cmt in $(eval "$first_log master")
do
    git log --format="%h: %s" --reverse ${cmt}^2 ^${cmt}^1
done
```

A brief explanation of what it does:
It loops over the input parameters `$@`, and adds as many `--grep` as the feature ids you passed. Then it evaluates the `git rev-list` command and for each merge commit found, it retrieves all the commits that belong to the second parent of the merge commit, which is the feature branch tip, but unreachable from the first parent of the merge commit, which is the previous commit in the master branch: `${cmt}^2 ^${cmt}^1`. The advantage of doing this is that it finds even the commits of the sub-branches originated from the feature branch.

To get the reverse chronological order, you just need to add `--reverse` option to both `git log` and `git rev-list`.

Input sample:

```
./script.sh FIB-13 FIB-34
```

Output sample:

```
429ab60: 1
c458a31: 2
1c0d098: 5
3bd087c: 6
```

Once you arrive here, cherrypicking should be quite straightforward.

Comment: Hmmm, the second part of the script (`git log`) seems to yield a different result. When I hand over the merge commit for FIB-34, it returns all previous commits (also from other branches/merges)? See: https://i.imgur.com/BUtVPKR.png

Comment: You forgot the `^` ahead of the `5d19020^1`.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. Also for the great explanation.